# Running :make closes the window

Tags: vim

I am using MacVim to develop a C++ program. I usually work with two side-by-side windows (header and implementation files). My problem is that when I run :make, the active window is automatically closed when compiling ends.

More specifically, the make window opens on a bottom window, and when it ends, whatever key I press closes the active window (header or cpp window).

How can I avoid this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it *actually* closing a window, or just clearing the output of `:make`, which scrolls the status line area?  Have you read through "`:help quickfix`"?

Comment: It scrolls up the status line area, but when it finishes compiling, and I hit any key, the window becomes an empty file. I will read the quickfix, thanks!

Comment: What's happening is that after :make runs, Vim is trying to load the file of the first error/warning, and somehow accessing a nonexistent or blank file.  See "`:help :make`" specifically (it's part of quickfix.txt) for what happens when you run the command.